# Error while arming cube orange plus using ros2 which runs on a companion computer?

Tags: cube, ros2, data-distribution-service, px4, autopilot

The connections are established between ros2 and px4 successfully using xrce dds , topics are being published from px4, when i use ros2 topic list it is working fine, but when i tried to arm cube orange plus, its arming but not in a single publish, when i tried publishing multiple times it is working, but it is also random, like sometimes it arms by publishing 10 times, 20 times, 5 times and even on single publish. why this is happening?

I tried using the same code for arming the drone in simulation it arms successfully in a single command, I didn't have access to oscilloscope so I cant check the wires and sometimes the client automatically disconnects and reconnects, we tried checking xrce client status in Qgroundcontrol when we press key to arm the rx in px4 doesnt receive any bytes.